# How to invoke info-getting from an Android fragment to the MainActivity from within the MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I'm trying to wrap my head around Android Fragments. If I put the following code in my MainActivity:

```
public void getMessage(Object obj) {
    Log.wtf("My object: ", obj.toString());
}
```

and the following code in my fragment:

((NewNotificationRule)getActivity()).getMessage("Yah wohooo!");

I get the "Yah wohooo!" into my MainActivity. The thing is that this pushes that string from my fragment to my Activity, where I want it to work the other way around. The fragment just defines a couple EditTexts, so upon hitting the submit-button defined in the xml called by the MainActivity, I want the MainActivity to pull the information defined in the EditTexts within the fragment so that it can submit it into the DB. So to conclude: I want to pull something (R.id.myEditText to be precise) from within my MainActivity instead of pushing it from within the fragment.

Is there any way that I can **pull** the contents of an EditText from a fragment into an Activity? All tips are welcome, since I'm totally lost here..

Answer (score 0):

One fast option (not sure if this is safe or recommended tho) is creating a class in your project with attributes needed to store info and instancing an object of this class in the MainActivity. Then, reference it from the fragment and fill in it the data you need to save (e.g. within an attribute EditText1Data or something) whenever the text is changed or introduced into the fragment's EditText. Then just store into the DB the data contained in the object you filled with the Fragment info. Place some default values to the atttributes in the constructor of this called class to avoid null stuff problems. This can help you easily transfer Data in both directions Activity<-->Fragments , even tho this mightmean you must be very careful since you can get null pointer exceptions.

//This is Your DataClass used to transfer Data between Activity and Fragment.

```
public class DataClass {
    public String EditText1Value;
    public String EditText2Value;

    public DataManager()
    {
        EditText1Value="Default Text";
        EditText2Value="Default Text";
    }
}
```

//This is the MainActivityClass

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    //instance of the DataClass to be passed to fragments with the method getDataClass
    public DataClass dataClass = new DataClass();

    //Main Activity code goes here...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
    }

    //This method returns a reference to the DataClass Object
    public DataClass getDataClass()
    {
        //Return this class instance object of the DataClass class
        return (dataClass);
    }

    //Now this is the method to push data to DB, called whenever an activity button is pressed.
    private boolean WriteToDB ()
    {
        //Suppose this receives a String
        WritetoDB(dataClass.EditText1Value);
    }

}
```

//And this is the Fragment that sends data through the DataClass Object

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    //Used to reference MainActivityObject and store info
    DataClass dataClass;

    //Used to Reference Activity's EditTexts
    private EditText editText1;

    //TextWatcher used to detect the EditText Field Changes
    private TextWatcher EditText1_Txtwtr;



 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever_layout, container, false);

            editText1= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.idEditText1);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            return v;
        }

    @Override
    public void onResume ()
    {
        super.onResume();

        //code...

        //Get MainActivity's DataClass object reference.
        dataClass= ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getDataClass();

        //store info whenever you need to, not necessarily on each keystroke, and store it in the object, not in the DB
        dataClass.EditText1Value = editText1.getText().toString();

        // Also, to capture whenever a edittext changes, you can use a textwatcher.
        EditText1_Txtwtr= new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)                 
            {}
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) 
            {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
            {

                dataClass.EditText1Value = editText1.getText().toString();

            }
        }

        //Asign TextWatcher to your Edit Text.
        editText1.addTextChangedListener(EditText1_Txtwtr);

    }




}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. The thing is that I would then need to insert data into the DB with every keystroke, which is not really the most efficient way of doing it I guess. Would you have any other idea of doing this?

Comment: No, not really you would not have to. Let me edit and place an example in code.

Comment: Again, this is a fast escape. What you should really do is implementing interfaces n the main activity to be able to pass information from fragments to the activity. But this solution will work greatly if your DB management is not so heavy. Plus, info can be seen easier within code in my opinion.